# How to move the last digit of a nine digit number to the first in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a code in SQL

SELECT

NAME,
ROLL,
PHONE_NO

FROM
STUDENT

I want to add a new column with in the same extract which will have the same 9 digit phone number value but the last digit should be moved to the first place.

For example: if the value is 123456789 then the value of the new column in the same row should be 912345678

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the modulus and integer division along with exponents to build the output you want:

```sql
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 123456789 AS val
)

SELECT (val % 10) * POW(10, FLOOR(LOG10(val))) + FLOOR(val / 10)
FROM t;  -- 912345678
```

For an explanation of the formula:

```
(val % 10) * POW(10, FLOOR(LOG10(val))) = 9 * 100000000 = 900000000
                                                        +
FLOOR(val / 10)                                            12345678

                                                        = 912345678
```

Comment: If going with this method, and you store your phone numbers as integers, use `(val DIV 10)` instead of `FLOOR(val / 10)` as it carries significantly less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use string manipulation:

```
SELECT
    NAME, ROLL, PHONE_NO,
    CONCAT(RIGHT(PHONE_NO, 1), LEFT(PHONE_NO, LENGTH(PHONE_NO) - 1))
FROM STUDENT;
```